# Truncating Actionscript Number

Tags: actionscript

I have a number in actionscript, arrived at via some arbitrary math:

```
var value:Number = 45 * (1 - (1 /3));
trace(value);//30.00000000004
```

Now, I would like to take the ceiling of this number, except in cases where the amount it is greater than the next lower integer is smaller than some epsilon. In the above example, I really want to round to 30, but only in the case where I know I'm getting a rounding error:

```
Math.ceil(value); //I want 30, but get 31
Math.ceil(30.1);  //In this case, it's reasonable to get 31
```

Is there an elegant way to truncate a Number in actionscript? Or easily discard any part of the number that is less than some epsilon?

Comment: Are you sure the first piece of code actually does not give you an integer with the value 30? It does for me, for some reason. Just curious.

Comment: In Flash Builder it is definitely showing as a non-integer. The specific math I'm eliding for clarity's sake: suffice to say that I'm getting 30.000(some number of 0s)0004 when multiplying 45 by .666(some number of 6s)667.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value:Number = 45 * (1 - (1 /3));
trace(value);//30.00000000004

// Play with arbitraryPrecision until you are satisfied with
// the accuracy of your results
var arbitraryPrecision:int = 3;
var fixed:Number = value.toFixed(arbitraryPrecision);

trace(Math.ceil(fixed));
```

Comment: My understanding ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toFixed%28%29 ) is that toFixed returns a string. Is the most elegant solution to really just cast it back to a number?

Comment: Interesting. Didn't even realize that toFixed() returned a string. That's the only trivial solution I can think of without doing this manually.

Comment: Incidentally, I would expect the AS3 compiler to optimize this String<->Number cast, so I don't think the performance impact is going to be significant, if any. Going to experiment with this later today and post some results.

Comment: I'd expect that as well, but I'm very new to AS3 and it seems like the compiler doesn't do a lot of things it should. Such as handle elegantly the same variable defined in two different scopes of an if-else statement.

Comment: So far as I was able to find, there is no better way to handle this than to cast it to a string, truncate and then cast back to a number!

Answer (score 2):

Is this method is of any help to you?

```
var precision:int = 4;
var isActualCeilingValRequred:Boolean;
var thresholdValForCeiling:int = 100;

private function getCeilingValue(num:Number):Number
{
  var tempNum = num * Math.pow(10, precision);
  var decimalVal = tempNum % Math.pow(10, precision);

  if(decimalVal < thresholdValForCeiling) {
    return Math.floor(num);
  } else {
    return Math.Ceil(num);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm upvoting because this is a decent epsilon handler, but part of why I'm asking is I expect this to be called many times, and having a whole function with multiple variable instantiations is probably overkill. Though I may just add a smoother function like this to my math utilities to help out. :/

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to round a number to a specified number of fractional digits is to multiply the number to 10^DIGITS to shift the decimal point DIGITS digits to the left, perform the rounding, and divide by the same 10^DIGITS to shift the decimal point back to the right.

```
var value:Number = 45 * (1 - (1 / 3));
trace(value); // 30.000000000000004
trace(Math.ceil(value)); // 31
// Round the number to 13 decimal digits.
const POWER:Number = 1e13;
value = Math.round(value * POWER) / POWER;
trace(value); // 30
// Compute number's ceiling.
value = Math.ceil(value);
trace(value); // 30`
```

It works for your example, but there's a big gotcha. If you change your value to be `450 * (1 - (1 / 3));`, your original problem will appear again. Now to get rid of it, you would have to round to 12 decimal digits. Basically, the significand of a double-precision format (Number) can hold about 15 significant digits. This means as the value increases by a factor of ten, the decimal points moves to the left and that last "4" digit you want to get rid of becomes closer and closer to the decimal point. So the code becomes more complicated.

```
var value:Number = 450 * (1 - (1 / 3));
trace(value); // 30.000000000000004
trace(Math.ceil(value)); // 31
var exp:Number = Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(value)) * Math.LOG10E);
trace('exp=' + exp); // exp=2
const POWER:Number = Math.pow(10, 14 - exp);
value *= POWER;
trace(value); // 300000000000000.06
value = Math.round(value);
trace(value); // 300000000000000
value /= POWER;
trace(value); // 300
```

As you can see, it now works regardless of the value's magnitude.
First, I find the number's exponent by taking a base-10 logarithm of the number's absolute value, then rounding it down. If you calculate `a = value * Math.pow(10, exp);`, then value could be represented as a * 10^b, where (1 ≤ |a| < 10), known as normalized scientific notation. But that's not what we're doing here. Now that we know how many digits are on the left of the decimal point, we will shift the decimal point right, but not too far, to keep one 0 and this error digit we want to get rid of, on the right side of the decimal point. So, multiply by 10^(14-exp), round, then divide by the same power.